# How is it possible to add condition to this code that if the employee is below the age of 30, he only has to pay half of his taxable income?

Tags: python, calculation, tax

```
income_input = {"Gerard": 120000, "Tom": 60000, "Roos": 40000}

def calculate_tax(income_input):
    for item in income_input:
        income = income_input[item]
        # print(income)

        if (income <= 50000):
            tax = (0.3*income)

        elif (income > 50000) and (income <= 100000):
            tax = (0.4 * income)

        elif (income > 100000):
            tax = (0.5*income)  
        else:
            pass
        income_input[item] = int(tax)
    return income_input

print(calculate_tax(income_input))
```

Output:
{'Gerard': 60000, 'Tom': 24000, 'Roos': 12000}

## So I can get a simple calculator using dictionaries. However, how can I add 'age' condition to that? As I understand the age should be added first to dictionary something like this:

```
income_input  = {'Gerard': 
            {'age': 50, 'salary': 120000},
            'Tom':
         {'age': 28,'salary': 60000},
          'Roos':
         { 'age': 25,'salary': 40000}
}
```

Then I have to make a condition for calculation that if the 'age' <= 30 then the employee has to pay only half of his taxable income?

So TOM and ROOS have to pay 12.000 and 6.000 accordingly.

Please could anybody help with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `income_input.items()` to have an access to the dict in `income_input` which contains both the income and the age (see `info` dict below). Then, you can access them by their keys.

```
income_input = {
    'Gerard': {'age': 50, 'salary': 120000},
    'Tom': {'age': 28,'salary': 60000},
    'Roos': { 'age': 25,'salary': 40000}
}

def calculate_tax(income_input):
    tax_dict = {}
    for name, info in income_input.items():
        income = info['salary']
        age = info['age']
        tax = 0.0
        if income <= 50000:
            tax = 0.3 * income
        elif income > 50000 and income <= 100000:
            tax = 0.4 * income
        elif income > 100000:
            tax = 0.5 * income

        # check for age
        if age <= 30:
            tax = tax/2.0

        tax_dict[name] = int(tax)

    return tax_dict

tax_dict = calculate_tax(income_input)
print(tax_dict)
```

Comment: This code works ideally. Thank you a lot! I see the logical order now :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the nested dictionary structure you indicated above, you could access the age of the employee with:

```
income_input['Gerard']['age']  # returns 50
```

Personally, using a nested dictionary with only two fields per employee seems a bit overkill to me.  You could consider using a tuple instead, and accessing the age with index 0 and salary with index 1, for example:

```
income_input = {'Gerard': (50, 120000), 'Tom': (28, 60000), 'Roos': (25, 40000)}
income_input['Gerard'][0]  # returns 50
```

Answer (score 0):

```
income_input = {"Gerard": (50, 120000), "Tom": (28, 60000), "Roos": (25,40000)}

for k in income_input:
    age, income = income_input[k]
    if (age <=30):
        if (income <= 50000):
            tax = (0.3*income)*0.5
        elif (income > 50000) and (income <= 100000):
            tax = (0.4*income)*0.5
        elif (income > 100000):
            tax = (0.5*income)*0.5 
        else:
            pass
```

I added age into the dictionary as variable